# iterator .end() from std::list returns "0xcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcd" but .begin() as expected

Tags: c++, iterator

I am creating a graph and need to return an iterator to the list of arcs coming from the vertex. I can return the beginning of the iterator just fine but when I return the end of the iterator it just returns "0xcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcd" and exits with error code 3.

I have a list of arcs in my header file set up like this:

```
list<Arc<V, E>> m_edges;
```

and my functions for returning the iterator as such:

```
template<class V, class E>
inline const typename list<Arc<V, E>>::iterator Vertex<V, E>::GetIteratorBegin()
{
    const typename list<Arc<V, E>>::iterator retVal = m_edges.begin();
    return retVal;
}


template<class V, class E>
inline const typename list<Arc<V, E>>::iterator Vertex<V, E>::GetIteratorEnd()
{
    const typename list<Arc<V, E>>::iterator retVal = m_edges.end();
    return retVal;
}
```

I then use my iterators as follows:

```
list<Arc<string, string>>::iterator vertArcIterEnd = (*it).GetIteratorEnd();
```

I use vertArcIterEnd here, the line immediately after initialization:

```
for (list<Arc<string, string>>::iterator vertArcIterBegin = (*it).GetIteratorBegin(); vertArcIterBegin != vertArcIterEnd; ++vertArcIterBegin)
```

Comment: Returning an iterator is not wrong, do you maybe dereference the end-iterator somewhere?

Comment: I think `0xcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcd` is deleted memory.

Comment: It will return what it returns but that will not result in any error code as long you don't derererence it. `end()` delivers the iterator BEHIND the last element!

Comment: Can you show us how do you use your iterators?

Comment: I call the get iterator function here:
`list<Arc<string, string>>::iterator vertArcIterEnd = (*it).GetIteratorEnd();`
and use it here:
`for (list<Arc<string, string>>::iterator vertArcIterBegin = (*it).GetIteratorBegin(); vertArcIterBegin != vertArcIterEnd; ++vertArcIterBegin)`

Comment: @Time `CD` is uninitialized memory, not deleted one.

Comment: This question calls for a [mcve].

Comment: To be precise, CD is pattern used quite often in debug mode to identify uninitialized memory more easily. This way if you see value CDCDCD, you can already assume that you read something not initialized. In this case you read past the list. 
Fun fact is that sometimes you may find a bug in release builds which does not happen in debug. It happened to me a few times because release version had condition on not initialized data which in this case happened to be zero. Debug version did not fail this way because condition was passing on non zero value.

Comment: @MaciejZałucki is correct: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations)

Answer (score 4):

The iterator returned by `.end()` is one past the end of the collection. You should never dereference it. You should normally compare against it, and when something else compares equal to it, that other iterator is no longer valid, and can't be dereferenced.

As for the value of the iterator itself, it's going to depend. In some cases, you'll get a raw pointer. In other cases, you'll get an instance of an actual object. A list will normally be the latter case, because the iterator for `std::list` has to overload its `operator++` and `operator--` to return the `next` and `prev` pointers for the current node (note: their actual names won't be `next` and `prev`, but might be something like `_Next` and `_Prev`).

For example, here's some code for an extremely simple graph (in fact, so simple it's really just a multi-way tree for the moment--but it still shows the kind of code you're dealing with for list iterators).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

template <class Val>
class Arc {
    Val v;    
    std::list<Arc *> children;
public:
    typename std::list<Arc *>::iterator begin() { return children.begin(); }
    typename std::list<Arc *>::iterator end() { return children.end(); }

    Arc *add_child(Val val) {
        auto ret = new Arc(val);
        children.push_back(ret);
        return ret;
    }

    Arc(Val v) : v(v) {}
    Arc() : v(-1) {}

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Arc<Val> const &v) { 
        os << "[" << v.v;
        for (auto child : v.children) {
            os << *child;
        }
        return os << "]";
    }
};

template <class Val>
class graph {
    Arc<Val> root;
public:
    Arc<Val> *add_child(Val v, Arc<Val> *parent = nullptr) {
        if (parent == nullptr)
            return root.add_child(v);
        else
            return parent->add_child(v);
    }
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, graph const &g) { 
        return os << g.root;
    }
};

int main() { 
    graph<int> g;

    auto child = g.add_child(1);
    child->add_child(3);
    g.add_child(2);

    std::cout << g << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I never dereference my iterator, I only compare it in a for loop here:
`list<Arc<string, string>>::iterator vertArcIterEnd = (*it).GetIteratorEnd();`

used in the for loop here:
`for (list<Arc<string, string>>::iterator vertArcIterBegin = (*it).GetIteratorBegin(); vertArcIterBegin != vertArcIterEnd; ++vertArcIterBegin)`

Answer (score 0):

Restarting my computer fixed it. When I did clean solution and rebuild that did nothing and when I reopened visual studio and did clean solution and rebuild that also did nothing. I didn't think restarting my PC was a necessary fix for this. My apologies

Comment: ***Restarting my computer fixed it.*** I don't think it did. Although your PC could have a virus or other hardware or software problem this sounds like you have Undefined Behavior. Anytime you get random behavior like this expect you have one or more bugs in your code causing Undefined Behavior.